# magento 1.9.2.2 not sending any emails

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2, email-scheduler

I have checked if the server configuration is correct using php script the server is able to send email.

cron AOE scheduler is installed and it does not show any errors.

Generate Schedules Every 15
Schedule Ahead for 20
Missed if Not Run Within 15
History Cleanup Every 10
Success History Lifetime 60
Failure History Lifetime 600
Mark job as failed after 15

cron job in cpanel set for every 5 min
php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php

Still magento does not send any emails.
No registration email 
no forget password email 
no sales email nothing. Please help me out.

Comment: are you able to check the `system.log` and `exception.log`? Are there any records on the `core_email_queue` table?

Comment: Is your cron set like this */5 * * * * /home/username/public_html/cron.php

Comment: You may please install smtp pro plugin

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the tasks being queued inside the cron_schedule table of the database? If not it could be a common issue with Magento cron and the way you overcome it is by the following.

After the line:

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Add the following:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

More information on troubleshooting the cron can be found at http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/troubleshooting-a-magento-cronjob/