# magento does not send any mail

Tags: email, magento1.9.3, send-mail

I am trying to send mail from any option. magento doesn't send any single mail.
Its return following error

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/XXXXXX/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:143
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(452): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(509): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#4 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('customer_passwo...', 'support', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#5 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(719): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#6 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(736): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/passwo...', 'customer/passwo...', Array, '1')
#7 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(763): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
#8 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->forgotPasswordPostAction()
#9 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('forgotpasswordp...')
#10 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I tried following code for checking mail enable or not.

```
<?php
$to = "you.mail@domain.com";
$subject = "Test email";
$message = "This is a test email.";
$from = "you.mailid@domain.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo("Your message has been sent successfully");
} else {
    echo("Sorry, your message could not be sent");
}
?>
```

Always return `else` part. also set cron job.

Also tried following code

```
<?php
if(function_exists('mail')) {
    echo 'mail() is enabled';
} else {
    echo 'mail() is not enabled';
}
?>
```

Return `mail()` is enable.

I am using `magento 1.9.3.8`.

[magento 1.9.2.2 not sending any emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91212/magento-1-9-2-2-not-sending-any-emails)

[Magento unable to send eMail, exeption error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53205/magento-unable-to-send-email-exeption-error)

Also tried to follow above links but not working in this case.

Comment: Can you check the server error.log for any relevant information?

Comment: @AdrianZ.`error.log` not generating